# Stripe payment won't work

Tags: javascript, php, html, payment, stripe-payments

Over the last two weeks, I have tried to make a custom payment form using Stripe, which allows the user to choose the price themselves and then afterwords charge their card when paid. The form for making the "token" works and is showing up in my logs under the Stripe dashboard, but the problem is that the charge of the customers credit card doesn't work. I am testing the scripts by uploading them to a hosting panel, I am using for another website, but when doing so, I get the following error "Internal Server Error" as in the image below.

[image]

I can't figure out what the error is, I know that the error most likely is in the .php script for charging the cards, as there is no problem getting the "token" from the html/javascript form.

My script html and javascript:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <!-- STRIPE PAYMENT JAVASCRIPT FUNCTIONS START -->

    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {    

    var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
        key: 'REMOVED FOR SAFETY BUT IS THERE IN THE REAL SCRIPT',
        image: '/square-image.png',
        token: function(token) {
            // get the payment form
            var $form = $('#payment-form');

            // Use the token to create the charge with a server-side script.
            // You can access the token ID with `token.id`

            // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
            $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token.id));
            // and re-submit
            $form.get(0).submit();
        }
    });

    $('#customButton').on('click', function(e) {

        // get the amount from #amount, round to avoid funny issues
        var amount = Math.round($("#amount").val()*100);

        // Open Checkout with further options
        handler.open({
        name: 'Payment',
        description: 'Payment',
        amount: amount
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

      // Close Checkout on page navigation
    $(window).on('popstate', function() {
        handler.close();
    });
    });
    </script>

    <!-- STRIPE PAYMENT JAVASCRIPT FUNCTIONS ENDING -->

</head>

<body>

                <!-- FORM FOR STRIPE PAYMENT START-->

                    <form id="payment-form" action="chargeCard.php" method="POST">
                    <input onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" name="amount" id="amount" />
                    <input type="image"  src="BidButton1.png" id="customButton" value="pay" alt="button"/>
                    </form>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        function isNumberKey(evt)
                    {
                    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
                    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
                    return false;

                    return true;
                    }
                    </script>

                 <!--FORM FOR STRIPE PAYMENT ENDING-->


</body>

</html>
```

My script php called chargeCard:

```
    <?php 

    require_once('./init.php');

    // Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
    // See your keys here https://dashboard.stripe.com/account
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("REMOVED FOR SAFETY");

    // Get the credit card details submitted by the form
    $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

    // Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
    try {
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => $token, // amount in cents, again
    "currency" => "usd",
    "source" => $token,
    "description" => "payinguser@example.com"));

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">addOne();</script>"';

    } catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
    // The card has been declined
    }

?>
```

Comment: you should check your apache error log as it's 500 internal error it will be logged (unless you've purposely silenced all error logging)

Comment: Isn't it `formElement.submit()`? No need to `.get(0)`. You should use AJAX or the page will submit to your `<form action` attribute value.

Comment: So I should edit the javascript part to say



          `$form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token.id));
            
            formElement.submit();`


Instead of 



          `$form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token.id));
            
            $form.get(0).submit();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your `Create` function and array are jumbled..

```
try {
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => $amount, // amount in cents, again
    "currency" => "usd",
    "source" => $token,
    "description" => "payinguser@example.com"));

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">addOne();</script>';
} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
    // The card has been declined
}
```

**UPDATE**

There were three errors here

1. Your `echo` was inside your `Charge::create();` function
2. You missed out your closing semi-colon on `echo`
3. (not the cause of your issue) but you misplaced the `"` for your `text/javascript`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have edited the script and tested it, but I still get the "internal server error"

Comment: @Sm00rf9000 you'll need to look into your server logs for any more information.. perhaps the `include` is incorrect?

Comment: I have figured out the errors, only problem is that the errors seem to be on the stripe-php file which is given by Stripe themself, so I have contacted them. But again thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You were passing the token in the amount field! Below is your code

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => $token, // amount in cents, again
    "currency" => "usd",
    "source" => $token,
    "description" => "payinguser@example.com"));
```

Comment: @Sm00rf9000 I am aslo facing same issue, can you kindly guide what you did to solve it.